# in typeorm if datatype is Promise I want to display that object in response using find query

Tags: nestjs-typeorm

in typeorm if datatype is Promise then it is coming in console but not coming in response

Datatype:-
`@OneToOne(type => ServiceRequest, {lazy: true, cascade: false, nullable: true}) @JoinColumn({name: "serviceRequestId"}) @Type(type => ServiceRequest) @IsOptional() serviceRequest?: Promise<ServiceRequest>;`

when I did:-

`let relations=['serviceRequest']; result.data = await this.ticketRepository.find({ where: { id: 87 }, relations: relations });`

Then in response I am not getting service request object.

And I want service request object in response